# How can Retrofit handle invalid responses from interceptor?

Tags: android, error-handling, retrofit, retrofit2

I've spent hours trying to figure this thing out, and I still can figure it out.

I'm trying to retrieve data from a website using JSON.
If the website is live and everything, it works, but if the website returns something else than the data, like a 403 error, or any other error, then it crashes. I tried to debug it, but I still don't understand what is going on here.

Here is my code:

I have a NetworkModule with an interceptor that is supposed to check is the response is valid or not, and from what I can tell it works, because my variable isDataRetrievable is false (the value by default):

```
val networkModule = module {

    single {

        val customGson =
            GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Lesson::class.java, LessonDeserializer())
                .create()

        Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(get())
            .addConverterFactory(
                GsonConverterFactory.create(customGson)
            )
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.URL)
            .build()
    }

    factory {

        OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(Interceptor { chain ->
                chain.withConnectTimeout(1,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                val request: Request = chain.request()
                val response = chain.proceed(request)

                if (response.isSuccessful){
                    networkStatus.isDataRetrievable = true
                }

                response
            }).build()
    }

    factory {
        get<Retrofit>().create(LessonApi::class.java)
    }

}
```

Next, I have my API to get the data:

```
interface LessonApi {
    @GET("/JSON/json_get_data.php")
    suspend fun getLessons(): Call<Lesson>
}
```

Then, for some reason, I have a repository (I'm not the only one working on this code, I didn't do this part):

```
class LessonRepository(private val service: LessonApi) {
    suspend fun getLessons() = service.getLessons()
}
```

Then, I have my splash screen view model, that is supposed to retrieve the data if possible:

```
          if (networkStatus.isNetworkConnected && networkStatus.isWebsiteReachable) {
                var tmp = repository.getLessons()
                tmp.enqueue(object : Callback<Lesson> {

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<Lesson>, t: Throwable) {
                        Log.d("DataFailure",t.message.toString())
                        nextScreenLiveData.postValue(false)
                    }

                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<Lesson>, response: Response<Lesson>) {
                        Log.d("DataFailure","Test")
                    }
                })
            }else{
                nextScreenLiveData.postValue(false)
            }
```

The problem is that when the program get to the line `repository.getLessons()`, it crashes with the error:

```
retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 403 
        at retrofit2.KotlinExtensions$await$2$2.onResponse(KotlinExtensions.kt:49)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:129)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

So onFailure or onResponse are never called. I tried to run the debugger, to step in, but I cannot figure it out when it fails.
I thought it was because it was trying to deserialize invalid data, but I put breakpoints everywhere in my deserializer, and it never hits the breakpoints.

I'm not a professional android developer, but I'm very confused here.

What I'd like to do is that if the request is unsuccessful, just discard the response (do not deserialize it), and display a message or exit.

Please help, it's so frustrating. I'm not sure how to intercept errors or what to do if Interceptors get an unsuccessful request (for now I just set a variable but it's unused).

Thanks.

**Edit:** What I'm trying to do, is to retrieve data from a webserver. If it cannot (for any reason), I don't want the gson to parse data (because it will probably be garbage and will not correspond to my deserializer). However, I feel like this okhttp / retrofit is a pipeline, where okhttp get the response from the webserver and pass it to a gson converter. What I want to do is intercept this response, and if it's not successful, to NOT pass it to gson, set a variable, so that the rest of my application knows what to do. But the thing is, for now, it just crash even before it gets to the callback in enqueue. The interceptor works just fine, except I'd like him to drop the response if it's not successful. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something like that, and it worked to handle bad codes (>400), but I also wanted to handle malformed JSON data, so I added the onResponse and onFailure callbacks, but it never worked, because when I receive a malformed JSON, it also trigger an exception, and then go in the catch before it can go on the 'enqueue', so I'm not sure what this is used for.

```
try {
    val lessons = repository.getLessons().enqueue(object : Callback<List<Lesson>> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Lesson>>, response: Response<List<Lesson>>) {
            networkStatus.isDataRetrievable = response.isSuccessful
            Log.d("Retrofit", "Successful response")
            nextScreenLiveData.postValue(response.isSuccessful)
        }
    
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Lesson>>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("Retrofit", "Failure response")
            nextScreenLiveData.postValue(false)
        }
    })
    nextScreenLiveData.postValue(true)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
    nextScreenLiveData.postValue(false)
    }
```

Anyway, just this code works for everything in the end:

```
try {
    val lessons = repository.getLessons().filter {
        it.lesson.contains("video")
    }.filter {
        DataUtils.isANumber(it.id)
    }
    lessonDao.insertLessons(lessons)
    networkStatus.isDataRetrievable = true
} catch (e: Exception) {
    networkStatus.isDataRetrievable = false
}
```

But in my API, I don't return callbacks, I directly return the objects, as such:

```
@GET("/JSON/json_get_dat.php")
suspend fun getLessons(): List<Lesson>
```

I don't know if this is the right way to do it, but it works. I hope this might help others.